# React - Can't fetch image from URL but works in C#

Tags: c#, html, reactjs, image, request

I've a problem which I find a bit weird but it is surely obvious for you guys. I'm trying to fetch an image as blob and then convert it to base64 to store it in Azure storage later on. I get the URL for the image from an object and want to download it as base64 to my react app. I'm able to get the image and put it into a html image tag as source , and it works just fine, the image shows up. On my server I can get the image via a HTTP client request and get it just fine too.

In C#:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient()) 
using (HttpResponseMessage response2 = 

await client.GetAsync("URL HERE"))
{
   byte[] fileContents = await response2.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()>
}
```

When I'm trying to fetch the image in my react app like this:

```
const response = await fetch('URL HERE');
```

**OR**

```
  const response = await fetch('URL HERE', {
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  headers: {},
});
```

**OR**

```
    let file = await fetch('URL HERE',
    {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    })
     .then((r) => r.blob())
     .then((blobFile) => {
         return new File([blobFile], 'FileName', { type: 'image/png' });
    });
```

Why is this happening in React but in C# everyting works fine and how to solve it? It eaither shows as CORS-error OR the blob is empty, size 0. If I click the link I reach the image so the URL is fine too.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

no-cors option is rarely a good way to fix cors errors. When you use React you use browser's system and browser send you a cors errors when it not receive a correct response. For example, if your server sends you a 500 error, oftenly you will not receive the 500 error but a cors error.
Did you try to make the same request from React with Postman ? I think, if it works woth C#, it will probaly works with Postman but just to try.
Did you make some console logs like this :

```js
 let file = await fetch('url')
     .then(r => {
          console.log(r);
          return r.blob();
     )
     .then((blobResponse) => {
          console.log(blobResponse);
          return blobResponse; // if you want to dl the file make a new File is probably not necessary : URL.createObjectURL(blob)
     });
```

Maybe it is a real CORS error and so you should check your server and API configuration. There is a lot of issues about it on internet.

If it is, try something like this on your API response : (do not keep `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'` on production)

```php
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Access-Control-*');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'HEAD, PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        $response->headers->set('Allow', 'HEAD, PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

Maybe you need too, to make a response for the OPTIONS http request. Browser send it before your request to ensure that your request will be received :

```php
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'OPTIONS') {
            return $this->jsonResponse([]);
        }
```

Comment: Yes, i've tried it and all I get in console is -> "from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

and in react -> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to fetch.

The problem is, the storage where we are fetching the images from is not ours. It is an external source.

Comment: In that case your are probably blocked. If you have a server, you can use it to be a buffer between the request and the response to fix cors problems

Comment: Hmm okey, I'll might have to go another way around the problem then... thank you for your support!